# Table metadata auto_increment value for table modification

Tags: mysql, table, auto-increment, metadata

```
if table X is modified(DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE) then
    table X's metadata value should get incremented.
```

I can write trigger for the same. But inbuilt solution will be better.

This way I can stop issuing meaningless SELECT queries on the large table, which will give same result as previous.

Server side program can tell clients that nothing changed on server. No need to query.

In other words I want to get version number of table, which increments after every modification.
I know [UPDATE_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) but for some engines, [this value is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003499/4417818).

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Can't you use an auto increment ID column?

Comment: mysql. After table update auto_increment will not change. I want to poll version of table.

Comment: Look at the default on the first `TIMESTAMP` field in a table.